# How to install and execute Icecat 17.0 from tar file

Tags: installation, icecat

How do I get the icecat 17.0 browser setup to run from the desktop, after I have untarred the tar file and created a folder for it?
I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and I have tried using the System->Preferences->Preferred Applications to set it up through the "web browser" function. PA will not let me point to the folder and the shell "icecat" (not icecat-bin, of course) and make it work from the desktop icon. I have already checked the box to make it executable; but I can't get any further with it. Otherwise it will not load from a direct double click, either.
What am I doing wrong?
I have asked this question in a forum called "the cafe" on the ubuntu-discourse.org site.
I did get some suggestions, and I tried them all with no success.
I was told it would be good to start my own thread; but i decided to ask my question here.
I'd be grateful for any help at all.
Ira Fromm

Comment: As far as I am aware, Ubuntu 10 is no longer supported on this site. Try searching the site for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Execute it from a terminal, like so:

```
/path/to/icecat
```

Then check the terminal output. It will say what fails to work so you can resolve it.

Also, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS is no longer officially supported and no longer receives security updates, you might want to update to 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that solution first. No success. I came here because http://ubuntuforums.org is off-line and down for recovery from a perp hacker. Goodbye.